# Crashlytics NDK uploads error, but does not show it?

Tags: android-ndk, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I've been working to make Crashlytics-NDK work for my team. I can invoke a crash using bogus C++ code, but even though I see an upload occur, the crash never appears in Crashlytics. I know things are configured correctly because crashes induced in Java code uploads fine. Looking for guidance on this.

I've got the

```
crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
}
```

block going on, and enabling in application onCreate with:

```
        final Fabric fabric = new Fabric.Builder(this)
            .kits(new Crashlytics(), new CrashlyticsNdk())
            .debuggable(true) // Enables Crashlytics debugger
            .build();
        Fabric.with(fabric);
```

Calling

```
String x = null;
x.length()
```

reports into Crashlytics. Invoking C++ code that's basically

```
assertTrue(false)
```

injected via JNI and externalNativeBuild does not report to Crashlytics console, even though I see a native stacktrace followed by

```
    CrashlyticsCore  D  Sending report to: https://reports.crashlytics.com/sdk-api/v1/platforms/android/apps/.../minidumps
                     D  Result was: 202
                     I  Crashlytics report upload complete: XXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
```